# Reading bundled data file (via pyinstaller) in Python app

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

**TL/DR:** Via pyinstaller, I have a onefile python Windows app bundled with a data file, but I can't read the data file at runtime.

Details:

1. I have the following Python script named 'test.py':

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import stat

bundle_dir = Path(__file__).parent
file_path = os.path.join(bundle_dir, 'data.txt')

try:
    os.chmod(file_path, stat.S_IWRITE | stat.S_IREAD)

    # Open the file in read-only mode
    with open(file_path, "r") as read_file:

        # Read and print the file contents
        file_contents = read_file.read()
        print(f"File contents:\n{file_contents}")

except OSError as e:
    print(f"Error: {e.strerror}")
```

2. In the same directory as the python script, I have a directory called 'data' with a single file called 'data.txt':

```
This a test
```

3. I build the exe (on Windows) and bundle the data file as follows:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data .\data\data.txt:data.txt test.py
```

4. When I run the exe, I get "Permission denied".

Sometimes, errors can be misleading. Therefore, as a test, I changed the name of the data file in my python code to a name I know doesn't exist. As I would expect, when I run the test, I get "File not found" errors instead of permission errors.

This leads me to believe that the error in the original script above is accurate in that the file is being found, but I don't have permission to read it.

How do I read my bundled file from the temp directory at runtime?

Comment: I just read the ref docs: "Although Windows supports chmod(), you can only set the file’s read-only flag with it (via the stat.S_IWRITE and stat.S_IREAD constants or a corresponding integer value). All other bits are ignored." However, adding those two values still results in the same error.

Comment: I figured out my mistake. The destination part of the pyinstaller --add-data argument is the directory name; not the file name. Therefore, my code was trying to open a directory as a file.